# Joomla site suddenly offline - using MS Azure

Tags: joomla, azure-web-app-service, offline

Was fiddling with some Google fonts in a module and all of the sudden it's completely offline.

I'm lost.

Site is

negoto.azurewebsites.net

Best

Answer (score 0):

to disable a module when you don't have access to the administrator, simply rename its folder, you will find it under ./modules/

Once you have access to the administrator, simply disable the module from the Extensions-Modules view; then rename the folder back and you can enter the configuration and fix what went wrong.

You can do the same for plugins, even renaming a whole directory such as ./plugins/system/ it's a very effective debugging technique when you have errors.

Another thing that usually works is to read the server error logs.